# How to get Cypress and headless Chrome to use the viewport dimensions in the config?

Tags: e2e-testing, cypress, google-chrome-headless

I'm running Cypress 3.6.1 with cypress-image-snapshot v 3.1.1 for snapshotting. It's on Ubuntu 18.04 with Chrome 79.0.3945.117-1. This is the command:

```
DISPLAY= vue-cli-service test:e2e --browser chrome --headless
```

vue-cli-service test:e2e wraps cypress, effectively doing something like:

```
DISPLAY= npx cypress run --browser chrome --headless
```

cypress.json has viewport settings:

```
"capture": "viewport",
"viewportWidth": 1280,
"viewportHeight": 720,
```

Snapshots in Chrome are 1050x720 rather than the specified 1280x720. This does not happen with Electron, instead the viewport is 1280x720. Any idea how to get Cypress / Chrome to run using the viewport dimensions provided?

**UPDATE**

I should mention this uses plugin `cypress-image-snapshot version 3.1.1` which may be related. Snapshots are 1050x720. Here's a minimal test.

```
describe('user login', () => {
  it('tests login page', () => {
    cy.visit('/login')
    cy.root()
      .matchImageSnapshot('test_login')
  })
})
```

And here's part of Cypress.config() log:

`"waitForAnimations":true,"capture":"viewport","viewportWidth":1280,"viewportHeight":720,"watchForFileChanges":false,`

Comment: This command works for me `npx cypress run --browser chrome --config viewportWidth=1280,viewportHeight=720` Let me know if works for you to add it as answer.

Comment: Thanks, tried but still get 1050x720. Strange but logging Cypress.config() shows viewportWidth": 1280, "viewportHeight": 720 in there.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Are you passing config to the plugin in `/cypress/plugins/index`?

Comment: Actually, I can't see the plugin using config viewport settings. You might have to preceed `.matchImageSnapshot()` with an explict `cy.viewport(1280, 720);`, as per this [test](https://github.com/palmerhq/cypress-image-snapshot/blob/8db0fbf780bd84fd15dd3badcc373664ccff5021/examples/cypress/integration/App.test.js).